# MongoDb replication does not work after system crash

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a mongo replica set with three VM nodes.
One is primary, others are secondary. While testing the setup,
periodic read and write was done using pymongo.
I observed three cases:-

Case 1: Primary mongo service was switched off using service stop.

Observation: Seamlessly switched from a secondary VM node to primary and read and writes continued without any data loss

Case 2: Primary VM node was shutdown using bash sudo reboot command.

Observation: Same as Case 1

Case 3: Primary VM Node was  forced shutdown from the cloud server dashboard.

Observation: The Secondary node was immediately elected as a Primary node but the read and write codes failed with a socket timeout exception

I suspect this is an issue with the MongoClient function of pymongo.
There is one brute force option of putting a try-except on every mongo query
but is there a better option ?

Comment: You maybe interested to check the retryiable reads/writes -> https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/retryable-reads/

Comment: @R2D2 I checked the retryable writes/reads and found that 1, It is already true by default and 2, It does not run the MongoClient init before retrying, which is required because the failed query gives a socketTimeout exception.

Comment: Btw , the easiest way to offload the app driver task to deal with replicaset is to convert it to sharded clister , that way the mongos will take the duty and responsability to micro manage the replicasets behind ...

Comment: @R2D2 I am not very familiar with sharding but my understanding of it is that it will separate the data into shards instead of replicating it, so incase of system crash, the data in that shard would still be lost wouldn't it ?

Comment: You can have single shard sharded cluster without separating data in multiple shards ... , but having sharded cluster is allowing the driver to deal only with the mongos ( the application routing service ) avoiding the trouble to identify available members , primary  etc...